# Cursor is out of bound: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0 error

Tags: android

```
 public static boolean setHighscore(String column, int newScore) {
    boolean result = false;
    String[] col = {column};
    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_HIGHSCORES, col, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int oldScore = cursor.getInt(0);
    if (newScore > oldScore) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(column, newScore);
        database.update(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_HIGHSCORES, cv, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=1", null);
        result=true;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}
```

how to fix this line? Because when I run my app shows this error above.

Comment: Please provide more information on what your code are doing , instead of copy and paste your code here

Comment: Have you check cursor size is greater than 0 or not?